# R tableHTML add_css text-align centre not working in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, tablehtml

I'm trying to style a table in a Shiny app using the tableHTML package in R.

When I use the `tableHTML()` function in R it produces exactly what I want. I use the add_css_column to align the text in the column to the centre. However when I use it in a Shiny app the headers end up left aligned and the rows centre aligned. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
output$viewers_website_top <- renderUI({ 
  tableHTML(website_index, rownames = FALSE, widths=c(200,200)) %>%
    add_css_column(css = list("text-align", "center"), 
                   column_names = names(website_index)) 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with bootstrap 3 unfortunately. Whenever you use `shiny` it loads up a bootstrap 3 css (immediately) which makes it difficult to overwrite.

As for the solution to this using `add_css_header` would probably solve this one. `add_css_header` would change the `th` tag of the HTML table to the one you like (whereas `add_css_header` would change the `td` tags below the headers):

```
output$viewers_website_top <- renderUI({ 
  tableHTML(website_index, rownames = FALSE, widths=c(200,200)) %>%
    add_css_header(css = list("text-align", "center"), 
                   headers = 1:ncol(website_index)) 
})
```

---

Another thing you can do is to add a separate css file with `shiny::includeCSS`. There is more info [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) and [here](https://lyzander.github.io/tableHTML/) on how to use `includeCSS`.

In the css file you need to write:

```
.table_website_index th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And that should do it!

P.S. `table_website_index` is the class the package assigns to the table which you can also change with the class argument.

P.S.2 I am the developer - thanks for using the package :)